# Don't work my jQuery code after append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Don't work my jQuery code after append. how can just change js code and worked it?

I don't use from ides "#aaa or #sss", How do without use them?

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sq4kx/**

html:

```
<a href="" class="qqq">Click Me</a>
<div id="aaa">
    <div id="sss">
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.qqq').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sss').empty().append('After typed must result alert: "This is ok" !??<div class="auto_box"><input name="we" class="de1"></div>');
})
$('.auto_box').on('keyup change', '.de1', function () {
    alert('This is ok');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this like,

```
$('#sss').on('keyup change', '.auto_box .de1', function () {
    alert('This is ok');
});
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/sq4kx/3/)

**Or**

```
$('.qqq').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sss').empty().append('After typed must result alert: "This is ok" !??<div class="auto_box"><input name="we" class="de1"></div>');    
    // bind event here
    $('.auto_box').on('keyup change', '.de1', function () {
        alert('This is ok');
    });
});
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/sq4kx/4/)

Comment: I don't use from ides "#aaa or #sss", How do without use them?

Comment: See `second demo` without `#aaa` and `#sss`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on('keyup change', '.de1', function () {
    alert('This is ok');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/sq4kx/6/)

Comment: I don't use from ides "#aaa or #sss", How do without use them?

Answer (score 0):

replace `'.auto_box'` with document.

```
$(document).on('keyup change', '.de1', function () {
    alert('This is ok');
});
```

*Reason:Why the above code works and yours does not?*

1.You are dynamically adding elements.In simpler words,the element you appended did not exist when DOM was loaded.

2.You need to assign [Event Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) for any future addition of elements.The method that we usually use like  `.click(...) , .on(..)` etc only applies to the elements that are currently in the DOM.

3.This is how you provide Event Delegation.

$(**document**).on('keyup change', '.de1', function(){.........})